# Merging multiple CSV files based on columns

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl, awk

I have below 3 CSV files. I want to merge them based on columns.
Combination of first 2 columns would be unique identifier.

I am okay with any scripting language, but performance should be good.

File 1 :

[image]

File 2 :

[image]

File 3:

[image]

Output :

[image]

Output in text format for testing:

abc,xxx,a1,b1,c1,p1,q1,r1,x3,y3,z3

abc,yyy,a2,b2,c2,p2,q2,r2,x4,y4,z4

def,zzz,a3,b3,c3,p3,q3,r3,x1,y1,z1

def,pqr,a4,b4,c4,p4,q4,r4,x2,y2,z2

Comment: And the problem with your code is...?

Comment: Please post your data as **CSV text** in your question, not as images. Makes it a lot easier to copy and paste so we can test solutions.

Comment: your last columns don't match!

Comment: *Combination of first 2 columns would be unique identifier* but you have multiple `(def,pqr)` rows in your files...

Comment: In `perl` the tool for the job is a ["hash slice"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices). Give it a try and see how you get along.

Answer (score 1):

Read the first file into a hash (what Python calls a `dict`), keyed on the combination of the first two columns

Read the 2nd file into the same hash, also keyed by the combination of the first two columns. You will need to decide how to merge variant data for the same column

Repeat for the 3rd file.

`Text::CSV` is your friend here....

Answer (score 0):

Check out the pandas library. `.merge` should give you what you need, but it's hard to say since you haven't posted any code. Anyway: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested due to lack of usable test data and the stuff in your images not matching your description of the data with regards to unique keys, but since merging multiple tables is basically a database problem, here's a script that uses sqlite to do all the heavy lifting:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: ./join.sh filea.csv fileb.csv filec.csv

filea=$1
fileb=$2
filec=$3

sqlite3 -batch -noheader -csv <<EOF
CREATE TABLE a(element, identifier, a1, a2, a3
             , PRIMARY KEY(element, identifier)) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE TABLE b(element, identifier, b1, b2, b3
             , PRIMARY KEY(element, identifier)) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE TABLE c(element, identifier, c1, c2, c3
             , PRIMARY KEY(element, identifier)) WITHOUT ROWID;
.import "$filea" a
.import "$fileb" b
.import "$filec" c
SELECT a.element, a.identifier, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.element = b.element AND a.identifier = b.identifier
JOIN c ON a.element = c.element AND a.identifier = c.identifier
ORDER BY a.element, a.identifier;
EOF
```

(Side note: Man, I wish [join(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) supported multiple-field keys)

Answer (score -1):

With the information provided, the below code should work for you:

```
cat file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv | awk -F, '![$1$2]++' > out_file.csv
```

N.B. - In case there are more than 2 columns in any of the files, the data corresponding to the first occurrence of the unique identifier (i.e. combination of first 2 columns) will appear in the output file.

Comment: That won't do what OP wants; it just prints out the first line with a unique first two columns, doesn't merge lines that share the same values for those two columns...

Comment: And you need an array variable name in that. Just `[$1$2]` by itself is a syntax error.

Comment: Saw the update from OP after I posted the answer. Will update the answer too. And, that piece of code works without any errors, though now that is irrelevant.

Comment: It certainly has an error- at least with gawk and mawk and nawk. Are you using some other awk implementation?

Comment: I am not a systematic programmer. But, I just know that it had worked for me. I have been learning things by exploring and trying out. I have used it several times on Linux and MAC command line.